# Is it possible to use the File System Access API to play a video on the local file system via reference?

Tags: javascript, file-system-access-api

For context, I have a video player written in Electron that allows users to load video files from their local machine. It does this by setting the `src` of the file to a local file path. This "reference" to the file is required because video files often exceed 5gb in size.

I know using the File System Access API it is possible to grab a reference to a local file but using the file appears to require creating an object URL, for example:

```js
const src = URL.createObjectURL(await fileHandle.getFile())
```

After testing, it seems that it is not possible to use videos larger than 2gb with this method.

Am I missing something obvious about the usage of the File System API? Would it be possible to use an alternative workaround with this (perhaps streaming the files contents somehow?)

Comment: "After testing, it seems that it is not possible to use videos larger than 2gb with this method." Really? Which browser? The File you get should only be a pointer to the actual file on disk, and the blob: URL should only be a pointer to the File's data, so there shouldn't be any limit because the <video> should be able to make Range requests to the disk directly. FWIW I can't reproduce on Chrome 100, where I am able to load a 3.5GB MP4 without issue using this code. Are you sure the browser can read the file when it's not from a FileHandle?

Comment: @Kaiido Hmm. I first tried this in Chrome 9x - I can't remember the exact version. I could have messed this up somehow though. Do you have the code you've written handy in a codepen or similar?

Comment: fiddles are hard to make (cross origin iframes) but just type `handle = await showOpenFilePicker();
file = await handle[0].getFile();
v = document.createElement("video");
v.controls = true;
document.body.prepend(v);
v.src = URL.createObjectURL(file)` in your console, that should do it.